# Newbie: hexadecimal editors to make sense of binary files

Tags: arithmetic, base-conversion

As a disclaimer, I am a geophysicist, not a computer scientist.

I have a binary file with a whole bunch of data in it (it is a large file; 221 MB). I am trying to convert this to something usable but I don't want to just find some online converter and hope for the best, I would prefer to actually understand what is going on. As a bonus, I have an ASCII file which was converted from the binary file a long time ago by a former co-worker, so I have a baseline of what is correct.

I have at my disposal a hex editor (not sure if this is necessary). If I open the ASCII file in a hex editor, I can easily understand what's going on: look up a hex-to-ASCII table online and you can easily convert the hex into a readable ASCII.

But what about binary? If I take the binary file into a hex editor, I can convert the hex into binary. But how can I convert the binary into something readable like text, headers, strings, integers, etc?

Really dumb this down for me if possible. For example, the first row in my hex editor reads:

20 02 00 00  26 53 53 42  89 b2 e5 c2  71 3d 76 41.

Can anyone give me a step by step intro into how to take this line and convert it to the matching data I have in my ASCII?

Comment: It is very hard task in the general case since we do not know what data represents, the hex editor just shows you data in different basis, sometimes offer preview of float/double, so it helps when data from converted file can be found directly. Otherwise your converted file (or software if you have it, even not usable) is the best shot. Do you have access to software producing files? The output data is crucial - these are strings? Integers? Fixed floating point numbers (like 221.34)? How files (converted and original) differ in size? What is the output format? Without these two files it is

Comment: impossible to guide you in any direction. Anyway, your question is (probably) off-topic here and asking about basic base-conversion probably would not help. Also software usage is not on-topic here, but I do not know where I could direct you. If this is standard software maybe some GIS stack?

Comment: Yeah, definitely off-topic, but what os are you using? In particular, if you just want to find ascii stuff in your binary file, try the "strings" utility, if that's available to you. What I write for these kinds of occasions is "prompt> strings filename|less"

Comment: You can try excersise like this - take some raster bitmap, draw some really simple things and open it in hex editor - you will find that according to type you can read header with information provided about it. After you find that standard 4 channels will take 4 bytes. Ok, readable, some are upside down, convert it to 24bit - now it is still readable but you have to know how to read it. Then try to convert it into JPEG or PNG or GIF and *do not read header from format description* - task got extremely hard, and this is very similar to your task. So even having converted one is not simple...

Answer (score 1):

> 20 02 00 00 26 53 53 42 89 b2 e5 c2 71 3d 76 41

Full answer is impossible in your case, instead I'm giving clarifications.

We should know the data format to convert binary file to human readable form or do a work similar to breaking a naive cryptographic protection. At layman's terms, we have an ordered set of senseless bytes without a clue. We need somebody or soft knowing what contained inside. Isn't there some documents? It's unusual to keep a final proceeded scientific data without any explanations how to use it because nobody else will be able to use it.

> I can convert the hex into binary

Hex is a binary representation, not a completely separate format, in general. The hex editor more comfortable way than reading 01100101. Hex editor can presume what these bits mean in integers, floats, rgb, utf-8, ansi and some other common data formats. If the format unknown it is useless as well.

For example, I can't recognize the format with one row. Somebody with a vast hexing experience maybe has a chance to do it. This string isn't looking as an ASCII (as you proposed) as a file header, etc.. It can be hieroglyphs from utf-8, but most of the binaries have some sense in Unicode (桂䉓늉싥㵱䅶). In ASCII it converts into something like (space) EOA NUL NUL SUB S S B Y (the next is not ascii chars at all) "b2 e5 c2".